# Create Facets based on generic data model in Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Our task is to implement an application that uses faceted search on Hibernate Search 4.6. Our database model is unfortunately a mix of relational and generic tables and it is not possible to change that.

This is a simplified diagram of our model. Our index is based on Entity but most of the data is stored as key/value pairs in the other two tables. The key is in table `PropertyType` while the value is in table `EntityProperty`.

[image: DatabaseModel]

This leads to these fields in the index:

```
entityname
entityProperties.propertyValue
entityProperties.propertyTypes.propertyName
```

The field `propertyName` would contain the facet name while the `propertyValue` contains the different possibilities. The problem is that the association between `propertyName` and `propertyValue` is lost.

We considered to move the properties we are interested in for faceting into the `Entity` table but this is not possible for many of our `EntityProperties`. We are stuck here and any suggestion how to solve this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think it would help, if you show actual annotated entities. It would show how these field names are generated. I am also unclear about the problem? What do you mean with "The problem is that the association between propertyName and propertyValue is lost"? Maybe a concrete data example would help.

Comment: @Hardy: hibernate search cannot handle key value pairs (column names as values in table cells), and therefore knows nothing about the semantics of `propertyValue` (value) and `propertyName` (key). This loses the association between them.